# Flutter Button in the 1st screen doesn't work after returning back from 2nd screen using Navigator.pushReplacement

Tags: flutter, navigation

I have a **next** button in the first screen, which when I press, it navigates to the 2nd screen using `Navigator.pushReplacement`. I also have a **back** button in the 2nd screen, by which I return the user to the 1st screen.

First time when I press **next** in the 1st screen, it navigates to the 2nd screen successfully. When I press back in the 2nd screen, it also navigates to the 1st screen successfully. But in this moment (that we are in the 1st screen again), the **next** button stops working.

I tested with `pushReplacement` and `push` and in both cases this issue happens. The only time it does not happen is when I use `Navigator.pop` to return from 2nd screen to the 1st one.

Dropping the animation part also did not have any effect. I tested it too.

Both screens are wrapped within the scaffold. Buttons are of the type `ElevatedButton`.

The button in the first page:

```
 wdOnboardingBtnNext(
                  handler: () {
                    Navigator.pushReplacement(
                      context,
                      PageRouteBuilder(
                        pageBuilder:
                            (context, animation, secondaryAnimation) =>
                                Sc_Onboarding2(),
                        transitionsBuilder: (context, animation,
                            secondaryAnimation, child) {
                          return SlideTransition(
                            position: Tween<Offset>(
                              begin: const Offset(1.0, 0.0),
                              end: Offset.zero,
                            ).animate(animation),
                            child: child,
                          );
                        },
                      ),
                    );
                  },                    
              )
```

The button in the 2nd screen:

```
wdOnboardingBtnPrevious(
                    handler: () {
                      Navigator.pushReplacement(
                        context,
                        PageRouteBuilder(
                          pageBuilder:
                              (context, animation, secondaryAnimation) =>
                                  Sc_StateSelection(),
                          transitionsBuilder: (context, animation,
                              secondaryAnimation, child) {
                            return SlideTransition(
                              position: Tween<Offset>(
                                begin: const Offset(1.0, 0.0),
                                end: Offset.zero,
                              ).animate(animation),
                              child: child,
                            );
                          },
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                  )
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Navigator.push` instead of `Navigator.pushReplacement` because in pushReplacement 1st screen is no more instead replaced

```
wdOnboardingBtnNext(
  handler: () {
    Navigator.push(
      context,
      PageRouteBuilder(
        pageBuilder: (context, animation, secondaryAnimation) => Sc_Onboarding2(),
        transitionsBuilder: (context, animation, secondaryAnimation, child) {
          return SlideTransition(
            position: Tween<Offset>(
              begin: const Offset(1.0, 0.0),
              end: Offset.zero,
            ).animate(animation),
            child: child,
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  },
)
```

Comment: As I have mentioned in the question, unfortunately I tested with pushReplacement and push and in both cases this issue happens. The only time it does not happen is when I use Navigator.pop to return from 2nd screen to the 1st one.

Comment: Add some print statement in the button when pressed to see if it displays text or not like "button is pressed". Also try other ways for pagebuilder like materialbuilder